# Create app.config file dynamically on Application startup

Tags: c#, .net, xml, .net-3.5, app-config

How can I create the app.config file programatically on Application startup (if the file doesnot exist)?

Comment: Can you specify some more details? I think it's obvious to you how to write a file to disc, but I gues that's not the real question. What dou you want to achive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since that file is just standard XML, you could just use XmlTextWriter to create it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it's it more appropriate to make your program handle that exception and then use default-values unless there is an app.config?

Answer (score 0):

You can save changes to configuration (by using configuration in the right way). This will create files at user-local or user-roaming levels, I expect it will at application level as well.

But consider that the user running the application will only be able to do this is he/she has sufficient access to the installation directory—this will not normally be the case (and will likely require UAC escalation).